# Wrong entry in /etc/deny.hosts file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosts-file

I mistakenly edited the `/etc/deny.hosts` file and added following entry-
`ALL: ALL`. Now, I'm unable to do SSH into it. After searching, I found that it denies all users from accessing the system. Does any one have idea on how to overcome this?

Comment: Remove the line?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I think the implication is that they have no access to do so.

Comment: @IMSoP... Right. Instance is running, but not able to do anything with it...

Comment: Is it a VM? AWS? Do you have physical access to it? Please give more details about the whole environment

Comment: @IMSoP then it lacks context on where and how the machine is hosted. If they have securely closed the door and throw the key away, it could be hard to come back inside...

Comment: Its an AWS instance

Comment: @ Serge Ballesta : I think it should have to have some way to overcome this...

Comment: @YogeshJilhawar: I've added the aws tag for you. You should give that precision in the question itself. Unfortunately I cannot help you more because I've never used AWS instances...

Comment: Meanwhile, since this is about systems administration, rather than programming, it should probably be on https://superuser.com (or maybe https://serverfault.com, I'm never that clear on the distinction).

Comment: @SergeBallesta Its a general issue and not related to only AWS. Anyways, I have added tag. and thanks for your help.

Comment: It may be a general issue, but it has machine specific remedies. For example: Physical access -> Boot from USB stick, VM -> Boot from rescue image, server with administrative network connection -> ???, AWS -> ???

Comment: Is it an EBS backed AWS Instance?

Comment: @franklinsijo..yes

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Root device of the Instance is an EBS, below [steps](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598) will help you to come out of the situation.

- Stop the Instance (`Instance1`)
- Detach the Root Volume
- Attach the Volume to a different running Instance (`Instance2`) as a non-Root device.
- Mount the device on `Instance2`

  - Find the newly attached volume name using `lsblk` and then try to [mount the volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html).
- Edit the `deny.hosts` file, it will be under `/mountpath/etc/deny.hosts`
- Detach the Volume from `Instance2` and re-Attach it to the `Instance1` as Root Device.

Comment: Wow, @mootmoot Thanks for the link (y).

Comment: Save all your typing in future :-)

Comment: @franklinsijo Thanks for the steps given. These steps are working fine. Im able to login to my server. Thanks once again!!!!

Comment: @mootmoot. Thanks for the link.
Link for more info-
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Comment: @YogeshJilhawar Glad it helped

Comment: Few points to add:-     
1) To find the attached volume name use command `lsblk`. It will give all the attached and unattached volume list. From there you can get exact volume name to mount.  
 2) volume attachment and detachment can only be done in instance's "stopped" state.